# Coding the mathematical approach for finding index of a permutation that has repetition

Tags: permutation, rank

How to calculate the index of an element in the list of strings sorted accordingly to the input alphabet having a given length and a given number of distinct characters.

```py
from itertools import product
def bruteforce_item_index(item, alphabet, length, distinct):
    skipped=0
    for u in product(alphabet, repeat=length):
        v = ''.join(u)
        if v == item:
            return skipped
        if len(set(u)) == distinct:
            skipped += 1
```

As an example

```py
bruteforce_item_index('0123456777', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8)
```

Runs in ~1 minute and gives the answer `8245410`. The run time here is proportional to the index of the given item.

I want an efficient implementation that is able to calculate that index in a fraction of second.

In other words: *How to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346937/index-of-a-permutation-that-has-repetition) problem?* A mathematical approach has been provided on the same page. I want a python or java or c# code as a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "rank" or "index" a permutation? What's your criteria for such numbering?

Comment: @Alejandro for example, what is the index of "abbbcc" in the list of all the permutations that have only 3 symbols of all 6 symbols.

Comment: Do you want sequences of exactly 3 symbols or at most 3 symbols?  Is "aaaaaa" a valid sequence?

Comment: @KyleParsons exactly 3 symbols so aaaaaa is not valid

Comment: May we know why you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I will explain how to get to a function that will enable you to get the index of an element in the sequence as follows

```py
print("Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index %d" %  
     item_index('3749832414', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))
print("Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index %d" %  
     item_index('7364512193', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))
```

```txt
> Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index 508309342
> Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index 1005336982
```

### Enumeration method

By the nature of your problem it is interesting to solve it in a recursive manner, adding digits one by one and keeping track of the number of digits used. Python provide iterators so that you can produce items one by one without storing the whole sequence.

Basically all the items can be arranged in a prefix tree, and we walk the three yielding the leaf nodes.

```py
def iter_seq(alphabet, length, distinct, prefix=''):
    if distinct < 0:
        # the prefix used more than the allowed number of distinct digits
        return
    if length == 0:
        # if distinct > 0 it means that prefix did not use
        # enought distinct digits
        if distinct == 0:
            yield prefix
    else:
        for d in alphabet:
            if d in prefix:
                # the number of distinct digits in prefix + d is the same 
                # as in prefix.
                yield from iter_seq(alphabet, length-1, distinct, prefix + d)
            else:
                # the number of distinct digits in prefix + d is one more 
                # than the distinct digits in prefix.
                yield from iter_seq(alphabet, length-1, distinct-1, prefix + d)
```

Let's test it with examples that can be visualized

```py
list(iter_seq('0123', 5, 1))
```

```txt
['00000', '11111', '22222', '33333']
```

```py
import numpy as np
np.reshape(list(iter_seq('0123', 4, 2)), (12, 7))
```

```txt
array([['0001', '0002', '0003', '0010', '0011', '0020', '0022'],
       ['0030', '0033', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '0200'],
       ['0202', '0220', '0222', '0300', '0303', '0330', '0333'],
       ['1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110'],
       ['1112', '1113', '1121', '1122', '1131', '1133', '1211'],
       ['1212', '1221', '1222', '1311', '1313', '1331', '1333'],
       ['2000', '2002', '2020', '2022', '2111', '2112', '2121'],
       ['2122', '2200', '2202', '2211', '2212', '2220', '2221'],
       ['2223', '2232', '2233', '2322', '2323', '2332', '2333'],
       ['3000', '3003', '3030', '3033', '3111', '3113', '3131'],
       ['3133', '3222', '3223', '3232', '3233', '3300', '3303'],
       ['3311', '3313', '3322', '3323', '3330', '3331', '3332']],
      dtype='<U4')
```

### Counting items

As you noticed by your previous question, the number of items in a sequence only depends on the length of each string, the size of the alphabet, and the number of distinct symbols.

If we look to the loop of the above function, we only have two cases, (1) the current digit is in the prefix, (2) the digit is not in the prefix. The number of times the digit will be in the prefix is exactly the number of distinct digits in the prefix. So we can add an argument `used` to keep track of the number of digits already used instead of the actual prefix. Now the complexity goes from `O(length!)` to `O(2**length)`.
Additionally we use a `lru_cache` decorator that will memorize the values and return them without calling the function if the arguments are repetaed, this makes the function to run in `O(length**2)` time and space.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache
def count_seq(n_symbols, length, distinct, used=0):
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 1 if distinct == 0 else 0
    else:
        return \
          count_seq(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-0, used+0) * used + \
          count_seq(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-1, used+1) * (n_symbols - used)
```

We can that it is consistent with `iter_seq`

```py
assert(sum(1 for _ in iter_seq('0123', 4, 2)) == count_seq(4, 4, 2))
```

We can also test that it aggrees with the example you calculated by hand

```py
assert(count_seq(10, 10, 8) == 1360800000)
```

### Item at index

This part is not necessary to get the final answer but it is a good exercise. Furthermore it will give us a way to compute larger sequences that would be tedious by hand.

This could be achieved by iterating `iter_seq` the given number of times. This function does that more efficiently by comparing the number of leaves in a given subtree (number of items produced by a specific call) with the distance to the requested index. If the requested index is distant more than the number of items produced by a call it means we can skip that call at all, and jump directly to the next sibling in the tree.

```py
def item_at(idx, alphabet, length, distinct, used=0, prefix=''):
    if distinct < 0:
        return
    if length == 0:
        return prefix
    else:
        for d in alphabet:
            if d in prefix:
                branch_count = count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                         length-1, distinct, used)
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    return item_at(idx, alphabet, 
                                   length-1, distinct, used, prefix + d)
            else:
                branch_count = count_seq(len(alphabet),
                                         length-1, distinct-1, used+1)
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    return item_at(idx, alphabet,
                                   length-1, distinct-1, used+1, prefix + d)
```

We can test that it is consistent with `iter_seq`

```py
for i, w in enumerate(iter_seq('0123', 4, 2)):
    assert w == item_at(i, '0123', 4, 2)
```

### Index of a given item

Remembering that we are walking in a prefix tree, given a string we can walk directly to the desired node. The way to find the index is to sum the size of all the subtrees that are left behind on this path.

```py
def item_index(item, alphabet, length, distinct, used=0, prefix=''):
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        offset = 0
        for d in alphabet:
            if d in prefix:
                if d == item[0]:
                    return offset + item_index(item[1:], alphabet, 
                               length-1, distinct, used, prefix + d)
                else:
                    offset += count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                length-1, distinct, used)
            else:
                if d == item[0]:
                    return offset + item_index(item[1:], alphabet, 
                             length-1, distinct-1, used+1, prefix + d)
                else:
                    offset += count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                 length-1, distinct-1, used+1)
```

And again we can test the consistency between this and `iter_seq`

```py
for i,w in enumerate(iter_seq('0123', 4, 2)):
    assert i == item_index(w, '0123', 4, 2)
```

Or to query for the example numbers you gave as I promised in the beginning of the post

```py
print("Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index %d" %  
     item_index('3749832414', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))
print("Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index %d" %  
     item_index('7364512193', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))
```

```txt
> Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index 508309342
> Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index 1005336982
```

### Bonus: Larger sequences

Let's calculate the index of `UCP3gzjGPMwjYbYtsFu2sDHRE14XTu8AdaWoJPOm50YZlqI6skNyfvEShdmGEiB0`
in the sequences of length 64 and 50 distinct symbols

```py
item_index('UCP3gzjGPMwjYbYtsFu2sDHRE14XTu8AdaWoJPOm50YZlqI6skNyfvEShdmGEiB0', 
        alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        distinct=50, length=64)
```

Surprisingly it is `10000...000 = 10**110`. How could I find that particular string??

Comment: Thank you. I face this error >> **Unresolved reference 'digits'** at the end of **count_seq**

Comment: Should be `n_symbols`, I renamed after copying and missed one reference.

Comment: **print("Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index %d" %
          item_index('3749832414', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8)) print("Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index %d" %
          item_index('7364512193', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))
    print("Item 0123456777 is at (0-based) index %d" %
          item_index('0123456777', alphabet='0123456789', length=10, distinct=8))**    **the output is:** Item 3749832414 is at (0-based) index 42375166
Item 7364512193 is at (0-based) index 55845106
Item 0123456777 is at (0-based) index -863100

Comment: Thank you but I've copy pasted your code and I couldn't reproduce your results and I've negative index for the first permutation which is 0123456777.

Comment: Let me check, because here it gives 8245410, probably in one of the edits I broke it.

Comment: It was on the same line where the `Unresolve reference 'digits' ` was happening before, I had wrote `(used - n_symbols)` where it should be `(n_symbols - used)`. Fixed now.

Comment: Please, update again, the coefficients were swapped, this happened because when I pasted that line was too long, and when I rearranged the terms I caused all these problems. Sorry.

Comment: You did a great work here. Thanks a lot. Some minor edits could be applied. There are some semicolons and, as my IDE indicates, unnecessary slashes. And also 64 characters on the last example is 62, so you need to add 2 other characters.

Comment: Thank you.
The last example has a 62 character alphabet but is counting words of length 64, length=len(alphabet) is only a particular case.
By the way, I came for the bounty :)

Comment: Could you optimize this code in any way to work faster? Item is a permutation of 256 bytes which will be provided as a list for `item_index` method. Length is always constant and is 256. Symbols are 256 bytes from 0 to 255. The same goes for `item_at` method. Optimize it in any way you can. Later my project will be converted to fast languages like c++ if that cause better performance, but for now for the purpose of demonstration it would be better to be faster than this. By the way, I've set a bounty to your previous answer to thank you for your help. It will be applied in 24 hours.

Comment: Could you please post this as a separate question with a minimal working example of what you want to optimize, including the testcases and your measurements. Thank you.

Comment: Asked the question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70940886/2123400

Answer (score 1):

If we choose 3 symbols from the set {a, b, c, d, e, f}, there are 20 possible combinations. We can record these combinations in a integer such as:

```
{a, b, c} => 1
{a, b, d} => 2
{a, b, e} => 3
...
{d, e, f} => 20
```

Then after we finish choosing 3 symbols from the set, there will have 3^6 possible permutations. Then we can represent it in 12 bits.
Take {a, b, c} for example, the representation can be:

```
 aaaaaa => 00 00 00 00 00 00
 aaaaab => 00 00 00 00 00 01
 aaaaac => 00 00 00 00 00 10
 ...
 cccccb => 10 10 10 10 10 01
 cccccc => 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Then you can use the combination of one integer and 12 bits binaries to index your permutation.

Comment: Nice solution, although this may work only for up to 4 symbols. For more than 4 symbols, some special encoding/decoding logic may be required.

Comment: How to rank / index these permutations without the need for generating all the permutations?

Comment: You don't need to generate all the permutations. Given a valid one integer and 12 bits binaries, you can find your permutation.

Comment: How to assign 12 bits binaries to each permutation, without the need for generating all the permutations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). This is pretty complicated to explain, but it helps you to solve the problem with `O(1)` time. This is [Project Euler's Lexicographic permutations](https://projecteuler.net/problem=24).

It finds a permutation by its index. Probably you can rewrite it by finding an index by permutation.

```java
public static String lexicographicPermutation(String str, int n) {
    long[] fact = new long[str.length()];
    List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); fact[i] = i == 0 ? 1 : i * fact[i - 1], i++)
        letters.add(str.charAt(i));

    letters.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

    n--;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; n %= fact[i], i--)
        buf.append(letters.remove((int)(n / fact[i])));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want an index according to all the permutations, but those permutations that have only a specific number of symbols from all the provided symbols. As in this question, 3 symbols of 6 symbols used.