# Optimization of a python code according to provided parameters to generate permutation and index faster

Tags: python, permutation

How to optimize [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687296/2123400) to work with given 256 bytes as an example?
Example bytes are:

```
bytez = [197 215 20 156 94 67 20 100 27 208 186 248 71 48 128 75 7 165 148 223 94 163 233 15 161 104 246 66 242 142 118 165 204 0 252 22 233 28 136 197 113 122 72 229 11 91 133 142 20 204 119 211 170 104 63 39 46 68 150 123 148 95 96 95 17 133 243 35 45 66 76 19 41 200 141 120 110 215 140 230 252 182 42 166 59 249 171 97 124 8 138 59 112 191 87 170 218 31 51 74 112 23 37 13 63 96 61 200 110 189 59 18 11 99 94 63 245 107 31 11 217 51 133 35 113 36 154 179 223 92 31 239 20 51 200 102 133 183 240 88 104 29 81 122 28 246 161 90 89 6 241 241 19 40 43 248 78 6 234 40 171 23 143 70 122 246 180 148 183 67 158 198 212 41 0 98 171 81 122 114 229 193 213 212 65 72 120 191 228 32 132 172 88 100 104 119 253 166 159 242 246 6 66 190 31 57 175 105 161 1 109 8 1 50 97 60 101 25 131 93 51 243 203 41 11 140 231 59 131 68 177 58 80 142 9 21 20 106 132 161 187 21 253 234 222 190 91 106 192 149 4 70 77 139 170 172]  
distinct = 156
```

I want both of the methods, `item_at` and `item_index` to work with a list of 256 bytes and not with string or integers.

**In more details:**
**For `item_at`**, a list of 256 bytes`l256b` will be provided as the `index` and for `distinct`(number of distinct bytes exist in the provided `l256b`) a value `0<=x<256` will be provided by the user of the method.
There is no need for parameters `alphabet` and `length` as both of them are always constant and are bytes `0<=x<256` for `alphabet` and 256 for `length`.
`item_at` has to return a list of 256 bytes, which is the permutation of the provided index.

**For `item_index`**, a list of 256 bytes`l256b` will be provided as the `item`(permutation) and for `distinct`(number of distinct bytes exist in the provided `l256b`) a value between `0<=d<256` will be provided by the user of the method.
There is no need for parameters `alphabet` and `length` as both of them are always constant and are bytes `0<=x<256` for `alphabet` and 256 for `length`.
`item_index` has to return a list of 256 bytes, which is the index of the provided permutation.

Comment: Rather than trying to alter a solution to a different problem, maybe we can find a simpler solution if you could tell us, what you want to do in the first place?

Comment: The question has been asked here and the solution works well no problem with that but optimization is required
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641665/coding-the-mathematical-approach-for-finding-index-of-a-permutation-that-has-rep/70687296?noredirect=1#comment125396231_70687296

Comment: to be honest, I cannot see an immediate way to optimize this, however you could try the numba package which provides means to accelerate existing python code by parallelizing independent for loops

Comment: @Raphael thank you. i'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1 - Handling lists

There are two details, one is that the solution was designed to work with strings, but it can easily be modified to handle lists

##### 2 - Tracking only counts of the prefix

That code is using is constructing the entire prefix, thus extending it each call, this leads to significant copy. In the function `item_index` this prefix is only used to know if a given symbol was or was not used. What can be done instead is to have a dictionary with the number that each symbol is in the prefix. Then instead of checking `d in prefix` you use `prefixCount[d] != 0`.

##### 3 - Adjusting cache size

You can see that the solution uses a [LRU cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), this type of cache will memorize only the 128 most recent elements, by default. You can decorate the function with `lru_cache(maxsize=None)` or simply `cache()`, if you know that the maximum length of the input is 256, using `lru_cache(maxsize=256**2)` is enough.

```py
@lru_cache(maxsize=256**2)
def count_seq(n_symbols, length, distinct, used=0):
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 1 if distinct == 0 else 0
    else:
        return \
          count_seq(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-0, used+0) * used + \
          count_seq(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-1, used+1) * (n_symbols - used)
def item_at(idx, alphabet, length, distinct, used=0, prefix=None):
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = [];
    if distinct < 0:
        return
    if length == 0:
        return prefix
    else:
        for d in alphabet:
            if d in prefix:
                branch_count = count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                         length-1, distinct, used)
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    prefix.append(d);
                    return item_at(idx, alphabet, 
                                   length-1, distinct, used, prefix)
            else:
                branch_count = count_seq(len(alphabet),
                                         length-1, distinct-1, used+1)
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    prefix.append(d);
                    return item_at(idx, alphabet,
                                   length-1, distinct-1, used+1, prefix)

def item_index(item, alphabet, length, distinct, used=0, prefixCount=None, idx=0):
    if prefixCount is None:
        prefixCount = {a: 0 for a in alphabet}
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        offset = 0
        for d in alphabet:
            if prefixCount[d] != 0:
                if d == item[idx]:
                    prefixCount[d] += 1
                    return offset + item_index(item, alphabet, 
                               length-1, distinct, used, prefixCount, idx+1)
                else:
                    offset += count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                length-1, distinct, used)
            else:
                if d == item[idx]:
                    prefixCount[d] += 1;
                    return offset + item_index(item, alphabet, 
                             length-1, distinct-1, used+1, prefixCount, idx+1)
                else:
                    offset += count_seq(len(alphabet), 
                                 length-1, distinct-1, used+1)
```

Then it will run in a few milliseconds in a modern computer

#### Iterative implementation

I am writing a class that you will instantiate giving an alphabet and the number of distinct symbols you want, in this case `distinct + used` in all the recurrences is invariant. The results of `count_seq` are precomputed in the matrix `C` on construction. The methods `item_at` and `item_index` are iterative implementations that compute the results based on `C`.

In my opinion this becomes less readable because in the recursive implementation everything is expressed in terms of function calls that have a clear conceptual association.

```py
class SequenceLookup:
    def __init__(self, alphabet, length, distinct):
        self.alphabet = list(alphabet)
        self.distinct = distinct
        n_symbols = len(alphabet)
        c = [0] * distinct + [1, 0]
        C = [c]
        for l in range(2,length+1):
            c = [
                c[d] * d + c[d+1] * (n_symbols - d)
                for d in range(distinct+1)
            ] + [0]
            C.append(c)
        self.C = C
    
    def item_index(self, item):
        length = len(item)
        offset = 0
        seen = set()
        for i,di in enumerate(item):
            for d in self.alphabet:
                if d == di:
                    break;
                if d in seen:
                    offset += self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)]
                else:
                    offset += self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)+1]
            seen.add(di)
        return offset
    def item_at(self, idx, length):
        seen = set()
        prefix = []
        for i in range(length):
            for d in self.alphabet:
                if d in prefix:
                    branch_count = self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)]
                else:
                    branch_count = self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)+1]
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    prefix.append(d)
                    seen.add(d)
                    break
        return prefix
```

```py
bytez=[197, 215, 20, 156, 94, 67, 20, 100, 27, 208, 186, 248, 
       71, 48, 128, 75, 7, 165, 148, 223, 94, 163, 233, 15,
       161, 104, 246, 66, 242, 142, 118, 165, 204, 0, 252,
       22, 233, 28, 136, 197, 113, 122, 72, 229, 11, 91, 133,
       142, 20, 204, 119, 211, 170, 104, 63, 39, 46, 68, 150,
       123, 148, 95, 96, 95, 17, 133, 243, 35, 45, 66, 76, 19,
       41, 200, 141, 120, 110, 215, 140, 230, 252, 182, 42, 
       166, 59, 249, 171, 97, 124, 8, 138, 59, 112, 191, 87, 
       170, 218, 31, 51, 74, 112, 23, 37, 13, 63, 96, 61, 200, 
       110, 189, 59, 18, 11, 99, 94, 63, 245, 107, 31, 11, 
       217, 51, 133, 35, 113, 36, 154, 179, 223, 92, 31, 239, 
       20, 51, 200, 102, 133, 183, 240, 88, 104, 29, 81, 122,
       28, 246, 161, 90, 89, 6, 241, 241, 19, 40, 43, 248, 78,
       6, 234, 40, 171, 23, 143, 70, 122, 246, 180, 148, 183,
       67, 158, 198, 212, 41, 0, 98, 171, 81, 122, 114, 229,
       193, 213, 212, 65, 72, 120, 191, 228, 32, 132, 172, 88,
       100, 104, 119, 253, 166, 159, 242, 246, 6, 66, 190, 31,
       57, 175, 105, 161, 1, 109, 8, 1, 50, 97, 60, 101, 25,
       131, 93, 51, 243, 203, 41, 11, 140, 231, 59, 131, 68,
       177, 58, 80, 142, 9, 21, 20, 106, 132, 161, 187, 21, 253, 
       234, 222, 190, 91, 106, 192, 149, 4, 70, 77, 139, 170, 172]
v = SequenceLookup(range(256), len(bytez), len(set(bytez)))
```

```py
%%timeit
v = SequenceLookup(range(256), len(bytez), len(set(bytez)))
```

`11.4 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

```
#%%timeit
v.item_index(bytez)
```

`7.57 ms ± 132 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

```py
#%%timeit
v.item_at(t, 256)
```

`33.6 ms ± 598 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

#### Specialized for bytes

An implementation using fixed alphabet `[0,..255]`

```
class SequenceLookup:
    def __init__(self, length, distinct):
        self.distinct = distinct
        c = [0] * distinct + [1, 0]
        C = [c]
        for l in range(2,length+1):
            c = [
                c[d] * d + c[d+1] * (256 - d)
                for d in range(distinct+1)
            ] + [0]
            C.append(c)
        self.C = C
    
    def item_index(self, item):
        length = len(item)
        offset = 0
        seen = set()
        for i,di in enumerate(item):
            for d in range(256):
                if d == di:
                    break;
                if d in seen:
                    offset += self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)]
                else:
                    offset += self.C[length-1-i][len(seen)+1]
            seen.add(di)
        return offset

    def item_at(self, idx, length):
        seen = [0] * 256
        prefix = [0] * length
        used = 0
        for i in range(length):
            for d in range(256):
                if seen[d] != 0:
                    branch_count = self.C[length-1-i][used]
                else:
                    branch_count = self.C[length-1-i][used+1]
                if branch_count <= idx:
                    idx -= branch_count
                else:
                    prefix[i] = d;
                    if seen[d] == 0:
                        used += 1;
                    seen[d] = 1
                    break
        return prefix
```

Using this implementation construction and `item_index` takes basically the same time, but `item_at` runs faster in my tests

`6.32 ms ± 91.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

This will of course vary, so you may want to try the same algorithm with different data structures yourself.

Comment: Could you provide a non-recursive version of this code? Trying to import it into Golang. In python `count_seq` doesn't work without `@lru_cache` I think the same happens in Go and I don't know how to apply lru_cache in Go. Also, non-recursive version would be more understandable. My goal is to make it even faster than this, so I'm trying on Golang for now to see if it makes any difference in performance. Please let me know if you think of a solution to make it faster. Thank you.

Comment: Using this command, >> `python -m nuitka --onefile myfile.py` made an exe version of myfile and it performed faster but only a little like 20 percent faster.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for your help.

Comment: on the third line of `item_at` I get error `Unresolved reference 'prefix'`

Comment: Simplified that, no need to thread the case `length==0` separately

Comment: Thank you. This is also faster.

Comment: why not create a dictionary out of `sequence` and `distinct`? this way there will be no need for calculations each time we get `v`? `alphabet` is also always the same.

Comment: The computations performed when constructing v are necessary when calling `item_at` or `item_index`. I prefer to do in the construction because then when you are calling `get_item` or `item_index` there is no work needed to get the subsequence counts.

Comment: The dictionary gets loaded on user's call not on object request, this way it will become faster to just look up for a `value` based on a `distinct` because in the construct the only parameter that changes is `distinct` and calling this construct each time before `item_at` or `item_index` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Is alphabet always `[0,1,2,3,...,n]`?

Comment: yes always 0 to 255, they are all the bytes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241795/discussion-between-bob-and-eftekhari).