# Getting permutation index and permutation at index faster than the provided solution

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing, permutation

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687296/2123400), here is how I'm getting permutation index and permutation at an index:

```py
import time


def get_Cl(distinct):
    Cl = []
    for i in range(1, distinct + 1):  # i is distincct
        c = [0] * i + [1, 0]
        C = [c]
        for l in range(2, distinct + 1):
            c = [
                    c[d] * d + c[d + 1] * (distinct - d)
                    for d in range(i + 1)
                ] + [0]
            C.append(c)
        Cl.append(C)
    return Cl


def item_index(item, distinct, n_symbols, Cl):
    length = len(item)
    offset = 0
    seen = set()
    for i, di in enumerate(item):
        for d in range(n_symbols):
            if d == di:
                break
            if d in seen:
                # test = Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][len(seen)]
                offset += Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][len(seen)]
            else:
                offset += Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][len(seen) + 1]
        seen.add(di)
    return offset


def item_at(idx, length, distinct, n_symbols, Cl):
    seen = [0] * n_symbols
    prefix = [0] * length
    used = 0
    for i in range(length):
        for d in range(n_symbols):
            if seen[d] != 0:
                branch_count = Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][used]
            else:
                branch_count = Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][used + 1]
            if branch_count <= idx:
                idx -= branch_count
            else:
                prefix[i] = d
                if seen[d] == 0:
                    used += 1
                seen[d] = 1
                break
    return prefix


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    Cl = get_Cl(512)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'{(end_time - start_time)} seconds for Cl')
    start_time = time.time()
    item = item_at(idx=432, length=512, distinct=350, n_symbols=512, Cl=Cl)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'{(end_time - start_time)} seconds for item_at')
    print(item)
    start_time = time.time()
    print(item_index(item=item, distinct=350, n_symbols=512, Cl=Cl))
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'{(end_time - start_time)} seconds for item_index')
```

```
356.3069865703583 seconds for Cl
2.5428783893585205 seconds for item_at  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 351, 458]  
432
0.025868892669677734 seconds for item_index
```

It works fine unless numbers get bigger, then it gets very slow. Wondered if it is possible to improve this code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71172244/2123400) answer that is improved version of the same slow function to calculating all the permutations?

The reason I get `Cl` in a separate line is that for a fixed `distinct` there will be thousands of calls on `item_at` and `item_index`, so the `Cl` is the same if `distinct` is the same thus no need for call it for each `item_at` or `item_index`.

**Update**: Test result from answer

```
0.008994340896606445 seconds for item_at
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 347, 348, 344, 345, 346, 349]
432
0.006995677947998047 seconds for item_index
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your inputs, and example parameters where the program is slowing down? For example, some of the 'bigger numbers' that currently are too slow to run, for benchmarking? Also, do you know which of the 3 functions is the problem (or all of them)?

Comment: For your provided example, 90% of the runtime appears to be in `get_Cl` to initialize a 300 x 300 list of integers. Are you able to use numpy, which is highly optimized for these kinds of tasks?

Comment: @kcsquared thanks for looking into the question. I've added some more information.

Comment: Do the permutations indices need to be in lexicographic order or is any consistent order fine?

Comment: @Dave Any consistent order is fine.

Comment: Can you explain what 'Cl' is? Also, are you able to use numpy?

Comment: @kcsquared Yes, I could use numpy. `Cl` is list of `C` and `C` was get generated for each specific distinct number of symbols on construct of this class in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944763/2123400 in which I removed the class and generate all the `C`s for later calls on `item_at` or `item_index`, so no need for calling on construct to generate `C` for each distinct. At fist `C` was `count_seq` in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687296/2123400, a recursive version of `C` which was problematic on bigger number of symbols.

Comment: @Eftekhari In you code example you have `distinct=350, n_symbols=512` yet the returned `items` contains 351 distinct elements (any why does it contain `351` and `458`?). Then, you should also provide the example for which your code is too slow. Using `next(it.islice(it.permutations(items), 432, 433))` is a matter of microseconds for the example you gave thus far. Finally, for clarification, do you want two functions, one for computing a permutations given the index, and the other for computing the index given the permutation? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will demosntrate two modifications that can be done to improve the speed of `item_at` and `item_index`.

Before we start let's initialize the Cl table, to handle calls with `distinct=200`

```
def get_Cl(length, distinct):
      i = distinct
      c = [0] * i + [1, 0]
      C = [c]
      for l in range(2, length+1):
          c = [
                  c[d] * d + c[d + 1] * (i - d)
                  for d in range(i + 1)
              ] + [0]
          C.append(c)
      return C;

Cl = {200:get_Cl(300, 200)}
```

#### Modification to `item_index`

Notice that the inner loop of `item_index` is simply incrementing `offset` by the values that don't depends on `d in seen` but not in `d` itself. If we know in advance how many times `d in seen`  will be `True`. So let's rewrite the code in a way that we keep track of the number of values seen before `d` in an array `seen_before[d]`.

```
import numpy as np
def item_index_bs(item, distinct, n_symbols, Cl):
    length = len(item)
    offset = 0
    seen = set()
    seen_before = np.zeros(n_symbols, dtype=np.uint64)
    for i, di in enumerate(item):
        offset += Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][len(seen)] * int(seen_before[di]) \
           + Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][len(seen) + 1] * int(di - seen_before[di]);
        if di not in seen:
            seen.add(di)
            seen_before[di+1:] += 1;

    return offset
```

This can be tested with

```py
pp = item_at(256, 300, 200, 300, Cl)
item_index_factored(pp, 200, 300, Cl) # 1.8ms
item_index(pp, 200, 300, Cl) # 5.39ms
```

#### Modification to `item_at`

For the `item_at` we can't simply group the terms as in `item_index`, but we can potentially skip some iterations, say that `idx` is decreased by `a` if the item is seen, otherwise it is decreased by `b`, so it is decreased by at most `max(a,b)` and it will take at least `idx//max(a,b)` to find the digit to be used. Then we do the update by multiplying `a` and `b` by their respective coefficients.

```py
def item_at_skip(idx, length, distinct, n_symbols, Cl):
    seen = [0] * n_symbols;
    prefix = [0] * length
    used = 0
    for i in range(length):
        a = Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][used];
        b = Cl[distinct][length - 1 - i][used + 1]
        c = idx // max(a,b) # d will be at least c
        ac = sum(seen[:c]) # the number of time a is subtracted
        idx -= a * ac + b * (c - ac);
        for d in range(c, n_symbols):
            if seen[d] != 0:
                branch_count = a
            else:
                branch_count = b
            if branch_count <= idx:
                idx -= branch_count
            else:
                prefix[i] = d
                if seen[d] == 0:
                    used += 1
                    seen[d] = 1
                break
    return prefix
assert item_at_skip(10**200, 300, 200, 300, Cl) == item_at(10**200, 300, 200, 300, Cl)
```

```py
item_at_skip(10**200, 300, 200, 300, Cl) # 3.16ms
item_at(10**200, 300, 200, 300, Cl) # 6.25ms
```