# Get index by permutation and permutation by index without making a list in python

Tags: python, algorithm

So, i want to create program, that will fastly return index of string in permutations list:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
```

I use something like this to generate this list:

```py
from itertools import product

charset = 'abc'
max_len = 3

for i in range(1, max_len + 1):
    for combo in list(product(charset, repeat=i)):
        print(''.join(combo))
```

So, it will be 6 for 'ac', 23 for 'bab', 'caa' for 31, etc.

I copied some code from other questions, but it doesn't really works fine

```py
import math


class Page:
    @staticmethod
    def from_index(index: int, chars: str) -> str:
        perm = str()
        for i in range(math.ceil(index / len(chars)) - 1, -1, -1):
            perm += chars[int((index / (len(chars) ** i)) % len(chars))]

        return perm


class Index:
    @staticmethod
    def from_page(perm: str, chars: str) -> int:
        ids = [chars.find(x) + 1 for x in perm]

        base = (len(chars) ** len(perm)) / len(perm)

        index = 0

        for i in range(len(perm)):
            index += base * ids[i]
            base /= len(perm)

        return int(index)
```

p.s. I dont want to generate whole list, but use algorithm to get values. It should work fast :)

Comment: Reverse each permutation string and see if you spot a pattern.

Comment: I can get just first (last if non-reversed) character of string in such way, I have no ideas how to get other letters

Comment: 'ac' is at index position 5

Comment: `len(s)` gives you the length of a string variable `s`, and `s[i]` gives you the `i`th character in `s`.  `s[0]` is the first character, not `s[1]`.

Comment: Yes, but i used indexing from 1 here)

Comment: Oh, I will try now

Comment: If you run this code here, it will return you very strange things - just try

Comment: I want to create something like here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207863/getting-permutation-index-and-permutation-at-index-faster-than-the-provided-solu

Comment: But I don't have number of distinct characters

Comment: You say permutations but your example data and your code show product. Which one is it?

Comment: I use product only for example, I want to **imagine**, but not to really generate this list

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for my question. Numeral system with base of charset len is something that I wanted to create, it works in such way.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from modules.config import charset


@lru_cache
def encode(n):
    try:
        return charset[n]
    except IndexError:
        raise Exception(f"Cannot encode {n}")


@lru_cache
def decode(s):
    try:
        return charset.index(s)
    except ValueError:
        raise Exception(f"Cannot decode {s}")


@lru_cache
def dec_to_base(dec=0, base=16):
    if dec < base:
        return encode(dec)
    else:
        return dec_to_base(dec // base, base) + encode(dec % base)


@lru_cache
def base_to_dec(s, base=16, rec_pow=0):
    if s == str():
        return 0
    else:
        return decode(s[-1]) * (base ** rec_pow) + base_to_dec(s[0:-1], base, rec_pow + 1)


class Page:
    @staticmethod
    def from_index(index: int) -> str:
        return dec_to_base(index, len(charset))


class Index:
    @staticmethod
    def from_page(page: str) -> int:
        return base_to_dec(page, len(charset))
```

config.py

```py
import json

config = json.load(open('config.json'))

charset = ''.join(sorted(list(set(' ' + config['charset']))))
```

It returns `' abc'`, with leading space (space is zero)

```py
print(Index.from_page('abcabcabc'))  # 112347
print(Page.from_index(112347))  # abcabcabc
```

It works in way I really needed!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really properly defined what you want in you question, but from your examples it seems like you want to find the index of a string in an ordered list of cartesian products of lengths from 1 to `max_len`, for a given charset.

You can do this without building the list by counting the contributions of each character from left to right. Note that for a given length `x`, there are `len(charset)^x` elements. You can use this to progressively build up the answer.

> So, it will be 6 for 'ac', 23 for 'bab', 'caa' for 31, etc.

First of all, both the length of the charset and the `max_len` are `3`, so we have `3^1` possibilities for length 1 elements, `3^2` for length 2 elements and `3^3` for length 3 elements.

1. `ac`: since we have a length `2` string, we already skipped all length `1` strings, of which there are `3`.

   A `c` on the third position means we skipped `2`, so we are the the `6`th.
2. `bab`: first of all, length 3 means we skipped all length 1s and 2s so we count from `3+3^2=12`

   (leftmost) `b` means we have skipped all that start with `a` and continue with any of the `3^2=9` length `2` elements.

   `a` in the second means we haven't skipped any for the second

   `b` in the last contributes `1`

   So we are at all of the above `+1`: `12+9+1+1=23`.

Similarly for `caa`.

And so on. Python code:

```
def find_index(string, max_len, charset):
    str_len = len(string)
    charset_len = len(charset)
    index = 1 + sum(charset_len ** i for i in range(1, str_len))
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        prev_pow = charset_len**(str_len - i - 1)
        contrib = charset.find(c) * prev_pow
        index += contrib
    return index
        
        
print(find_index('caa', 3, 'abc'))
```

You can probably further optimize this by not calling `**` at each step, but it's quite fast as it is.

Similar reasoning should allow you to go from an index to the string at that position.

Comment: In Python3, the `**` operator returns an `int` if both operands are `int` and the second operand is >=0. Also,  `sum(b**i for i in range(n))` is `(b**n-1)//(b-1)`. (`b**n - 1` written out in base `b` is n repetitions of the digit b-1).